# jQuery not toggling div display property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

experiencing a very strange bug that I can't seem to get past.

I have no syntax errors in my web console, and yet I still can't get my function to work.

I'm simply toggling a div via .slideToggle(), but it is not registering my click event.

Here is my HTML;

```
<div id="btnAcc" title="Log In"></div>

    <div id="userMenu">

        // Some Stuff

    </div>
```

And here is my JS:

// APP BAR

```
    $('#btnAcc').click(function(){
        $('#userMenu').slideToggle();           
    });
```

When I issue $('#userMenu').slideToggle(); in my web console, the div slides down. But I can't get it to work when I click the div.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle.net example that does this? Is your userMenu element added dynamically?

Comment: My feeling is that you're attaching the event before the element exist on the DOM. Be sure that the code is on document ready event or after the html element definition.

Comment: ^ How can I test this? I have everything wrapped in a document.ready

Comment: btw in this code you dont have syntax errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DOM has not fully loaded when your jQuery runs. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnAcc').click(function(){
        $('#userMenu').slideToggle();           
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow, I just happened to accidently add my code below my last }); closing brackets. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the event like this :

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnAcc', function() {
    $('#userMenu').slideToggle();
});
```

You are most likely trying to assign an event to an HTML element that has not been loaded into the DOM yet.